# OpenWrt AP in client mode has really slow download

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-access-point, openwrt

I have OpenWrt installed on a TP-Link WA801ND access point running in client mode connected to another (corporate wifi) network.

I believe the connection to the corporate network is strong.  See screenshot below from the Luci web interface - I'm not sure what all the numbers mean, but they look OK to me.

[image: Luci connection info]

It's been running fine for a few weeks, but the upstream corporate wireless AP hardware was "upgraded" recently to a new model (some Cisco box a few metres away from my WA801ND), and the download speed has been terrible since then.

I isolated the slowness to the WA801ND itself.  That is, an old Android tablet (2.4GHz-only, same as the WA801ND) gets reasonable speeds.  But `ssh`-ing into the WA801ND and `wget`-ing a test file is abysmally slow (see pic).

[image: OpenWrt ssh session]

I've tried fiddling all sorts of settings I don't understand in the Luci web interface, and then in the raw config files themselves, based on half-hints I've found on the web.  But nothing has helped.

Anyone got any hints on things to try?

Comment: How does it perform when you connect it to a different Wi-Fi network?

Comment: Erm, unless you are in the mountains or something. that is NOT a real signal to noise reading, there is zero noise... I would factory reset and make sure you have your chipsets drivers running. Not generic ones.